# run vb script from other script

Tags: vbscript

I have for example two VB script:

Test1.vb
Test2.vb

How to run Test2.vb from Test1.vb

Test2.vb location :  C:\Program Files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
Dim obj
Set obj = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
obj.Run "C:\Program Files\Test2.vbs"
```

Comment: another quastion
if Test2.vbs ended then he return to Test1.vbs?
yael

Comment: @yael: Yes, after Test2 has finished execution should go back to Test1.

Comment: will line #3 wait until `Test2.vbs` finishes executing before proceeding to line #4?

Comment: @JohnB: Depends on the 3rd (optional) parameter. By default it won't wait, but if you set the 3rd parameter to `true` it will. See here for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Run the script from WScript.shell object.